# How to compute the square root also from negative number?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib

I got the following error and am not sure of its origin:

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Thus, I wrote

```
    if om_dif > 0:
```

and I got `SIGKILL`

The aim is to obtain list `k` including the result for negative `om_dif` and positive `om_dif`.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

omega = np.linspace(0, 1128, 10000)
e = 1.602176634e-19
m_e = 9.1093837015e-31
eps_0 = 8.8541878128e-12
n_0 = 0.00032
c = 1
omega_p = np.sqrt(n_0*e**2/(eps_0*m_e))        
k = []


############
for i in omega:
    om_dif = omega**2-omega_p**2

    if om_dif > 0:
        kk = np.sqrt((om_dif)/c**2)
    else:
        kk = np.sqrt((abs(om_dif))/c**2)
    k.append(kk)

##############

v_phi = omega/k

ax.set_xlim(0, 2*omega_p)
ax.set_ylim(-4, 4)

ax.plot(v_phi**2/c**2, omega)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can avoid the loop by using `numpy` functions to perform the computation directly using arrays. (It is also much faster)

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

omega = np.linspace(0, 1128, 10000)
e = 1.602176634e-19
m_e = 9.1093837015e-31
eps_0 = 8.8541878128e-12
n_0 = 0.00032
c = 1
omega_p = np.sqrt(n_0*e**2/(eps_0*m_e))        

k = np.sqrt((np.abs(omega**2 - omega_p**2))/c**2)

fig, ax=plt.subplots(1)
v_phi = omega / np.array(k)

ax.set_xlim(0, 2*omega_p)
ax.set_ylim(-4, 4)

ax.plot(v_phi**2/c**2, omega)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To specifically address the error message, the issue lies in that you correctly iterate over the omega array, but you then operate on the entire array instead of the array's value for id `i`

```
[...]
for i in omega:
    om_dif = omega[i]**2-omega_p[i]**2
[...]
```

You would also gain compute time by not bothering testing if `om_dif` is positive and always applying the `abs()` function to your value.

```
for i in omega:
    om_dif = omega[i]**2-omega_p[i]**2

    k.append(np.sqrt((abs(om_dif))/c**2))
```

On the actual method, @[Andrea](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8103056/andrea)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65845090/311288) seems to best leverage the `numpy` library.